# Создать массив из 4 случайных целых чисел из отрезка [10;99]

Tags: java

Создаю массив из 4 случайных целых чисел из отрезка [10;99],нужно вывести его на экран в строку. Определить и вывести на экран сообщение о том, является ли массив строго возрастающей последовательностью.
Не знаю, что дальше делать, может весь пример неправильный, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] Mas = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < Mas.length; i++) {
            Mas[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 90 + 10);
            System.out.print(Mas[i] + " ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Mas.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                if (Mas[i - 1] >= Mas[i]) {
                    System.out.println("Прогрессия не возрастающая");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужен метод рандомного числа из диапазона

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;

}
```

Далее реализация

```
int[] Mas = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < Mas.length; i++) {
    Mas[i] = randInt(10, 99);
    System.out.print(Mas[i] + " ");
}

String result = "Прогрессия возрастающая";
for (int i = 0; i < Mas.length; i++) {
   if (i > 0 && Mas[i - 1] >= Mas[i]) {
      result = "Прогрессия не возрастающая";
      break;
   }      
}
System.out.print(result);
```